# Why can't errno's value be printed?

Tags: c, gdb, errno

I am looking at the following code in an SO "Low Quality" post to make sure the sample works, and my question is why can't I print errno's value?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <errno.h>

int main(){
    FILE *fp;
    errno = 0;
    fp=fopen("Not_exist.txt","r");
    if(fp == NULL && errno == ENOENT)
        perror("file not exist");
    return 0;
}
```

Here is what happens when I try to print the value:

```
(gdb) p errno
Cannot find thread-local variables on this target
(gdb)
```

I can print fp's value just fine. As you would expect it's value is `0x00`.

I looked at `/usr/include/errno.h` and a lot of the other include files included as part of `errno.h`, and I cannot figure out how errno is defined. Any pointers or help would be appreciated. I'm just curious about it; nothing is broken.

Thank you.

Comment: Try using `ferror(my-file-pointer)` next time instead.

Comment: Can you print the value of `errno` from your program? `printf("errno = %d\n", errno);`

Comment: Is it possible to print `errno` also when examining a core dump? As at that time you cannot run any functions.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In my Ubuntu installation, I have the following section in `bits/errno.h`:

```
/* Function to get address of global `errno' variable.  */
extern int *__errno_location (void) __THROW __attribute__ ((__const__));

#  if !defined _LIBC || defined _LIBC_REENTRANT
/* When using threads, errno is a per-thread value.  */
#   define errno (*__errno_location ())
#  endif
```

That said, `errno` is not necessarily a variable. For various reasons you may want to have a function returning the error value for you rather than a simple `extern int`.<sup>1</sup> That is why you can't print its value using GDB.

<sup>1</sup> <sub>of course, as you can see the function call should return the pointer to the actual variable and the `errno` macro would dereference it.</sub>

Comment: `errno` is necessarily an *lvalue*, so you can assign to it.

Comment: @KeithThompson, I didn't say it's not an lvalue. I said it's not necessarily a variable. gdb, or at least that particular version, would be able to read a location of memory marked by a name (for example variable `i`), but _may_ not (as seems to be in this case) execute a function to return its value.

Comment: My point is that `errno` can't be (a macro defined as) a function that returns the `int` *value*; the second sentence in your last paragraph could imply that it can be. It can, of course, be a macro that expands to an expression containing a call to a function that returns an `int*`.

Comment: @KeithThompson, I added a comment to clarify.

Answer (score 14):

The `errno` variable is kind of an odd duck. Because most runtime libraries these days support threads, there can't be just *one* `errno` variable. If there were, then two threads could do things at the same time that both set the `errno` value, and great confusion would ensue.

Runtime libraries do various tricks to avoid this problem. For example, one might do something like:

```
#define errno __get_errno()
```

where references to `errno` actually call the internal `__get_errno()` function, which returns the correct error number value for the current thread. The disadvantage of this method is it prevents assignment to errno, such as `errno = 0;` (which some code might do). Runtime libraries will usually choose a more sophisticated approach.

Some runtime libraries (like the one you're using, I suppose) can declare a special type of "thread-local variable" which can have a different value on each thread. It sounds like your debugger on your system can't display that kind of variable.

Comment: The approach I've seen is `#define errno *__get_errno()`; `__get_errno()` returns a pointer and the macro dereferences it. This way, it's assignable _and_ still encapsulated in a function.

Comment: Yes, that's one way of doing thread-local storage without specific compiler support.

Answer (score 8):

As others have said, `errno` is not a variable that gdb can print. But gdb can
evaluate functions, and `__errno_location()` returns a pointer to `errno'. The only thing we need to do then, is to call the function and dereference the restult:

```
(gdb) p *__errno_location()
```

And that's it.

Answer (score 6):

`errno` is actually required by the C standard to be a macro that expands to a modifiable lvalue.  In the simplest case, it can expand to the name of a declared variable, but for implementations that need distinct `errno` objects for different threads, it's typically defined something like this:

```
#define errno (*__errno_location ())
```

`gdb` is usually able to evaluate function calls; for example, on my system:

```
(gdb) p __errno_location()
$1 = -134383968
(gdb) p errno
Cannot find thread-local variables on this target
```

The first printed value happens to be the low-order 32 bits of the pointer value returned by `__errno_location()`.  I don't know gdb well enough to explain that behavior, but it does demonstrate that it can execute function calls.

As a workaround, you can modify the source code so that it saves either the address of `errno`, or its value, in a variable that gdb can display:

```
(gdb) l
1       #include <errno.h>
2       #include <stdio.h>
3       int main(void) {
4           errno = 42; /* arbitrary value */
5           const int *errno_ptr = &errno;
6           int errno_value = errno;
7           printf("%d %d %d\n", errno, errno_value, *errno_ptr);
8       }
(gdb) b 8
Breakpoint 1 at 0x4005b6: file c.c, line 8.
(gdb) r
Starting program: /home/kst/c 
42 42 42

Breakpoint 1, main () at c.c:8
8       }
(gdb) p errno
Cannot find thread-local variables on this target
(gdb) p errno_value
$1 = 42
(gdb) p *errno_ptr
$2 = 42
```

The `*errno_ptr` approach has the advantage that you only have to assign it once -- unless you're debugging a multi-threaded program. In that case, the value of `&errno` can vary depending on the thread in which you evaluate it.

This is probably a bug, or at least a missing feature, in `gdb`.

**UPDATE** Kevin Cox's comment suggests a workaround:

```
print *((int*(*)())__errno_location)()
```

And with gcc 6.2 and gdb 7.11, `print errno` actually works:

```
(gdb) l
1       #include <errno.h>
2       int main(void) {
3           errno = 42;
4           return 0;
5       }
(gdb) b 4
Breakpoint 1 at 0x6bf: file c.c, line 4.
(gdb) r
Starting program: /home/kst/c 

Breakpoint 1, main () at c.c:4
4           return 0;
(gdb) p errno
$1 = 42
(gdb)
```

Comment: The reason it is getting truncated is because there is no debugging information providing the signature for the function so gdb assumes that it is int(*)() when it actually returns an int*. To work around this you can cast the symbol to the proper function type before you call it `print *((int*(*)())__errno_location)()`

Comment: Note that if you compile with debug symbols printing `errno` will always work, the problem is if you don't have debug symbols the compiler doesn't know what errno is (because it is a macro).

Comment: @KevinCox: Hmm. I was assuming that if you're going to use `gdb`, you need to compile with debug symbols (`gcc -g ...`) anyway.

Comment: You don't need to and sometimes you are stuck in an unfortunate situation where the symbols aren't available. Trust me, when there are no symbols available being able to read errno is a *huuuuge* benefit.

Answer (score 1):

```
_CRTIMP int* __cdecl __MINGW_NOTHROW _errno(void);
#define errno       (*_errno())
```

This is used so that, you can just pass the address of a preferred veriable which will contain the actual error value returned from the calling function.

E.g. You can define the function _errno() as below

```
unsigned int errorValue;

int* _errno()
{
    return (&errorValue);
}
```

Now usage:

```
void MyFunc()
{
  if(some condition failure)
      errno = 10; //Or any error value as per your design
  else
  {
     //Actual operation
  }
}
```

After `MyFunc()` is executed, `errorValue` will contain the error.

Comment: How does this answer the question?